# Disk partitioning for dual boot (ssd)

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, disk-management

I've just bought a laptop with 8GB ram, i5 8th gen processor and 512 GB ssd.
Presently I've Win 10 operating system and I wish to dual boot, adding a linux based OS (ubuntu 18.04 LTS maybe). **Please suggest me an ideal disk partition**.
I use linux for programming (intermediate/scientific) and simple simulations and windows for basic work and use MS-Office,emails,dropbox, watching videos etc.

Comment: "Please suggest me an ideal disk partition"  There is no such thing only why you, me or someone else likes for their setup.

Comment: i suggest to completely remove the snitch Win10